# Blowfish password verifying

Tags: java, spring-security, blowfish

I use Spring security in this question but its knowledge might not be required to answer this question.

I am trying to understand how Spring security's blowfish encryption class (`BCrypt`) verifies a given password. I tried to :

1. Generate a Salt with `BCrypt.gensalt(10);`
2. Encode a password using this salt with `BCrypt.hashpw(clearText, salt)`.

It worked well.Then, I wanted to store the used salt in the database in order to be able to reuse it when the users enter a password.

I realized that `BCryptPasswordEncoder` does not use the salt when it checks the password. Instead, it crypts the password with its hashed password as salt :

```
public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
  [...]
  return BCrypt.checkpw(rawPassword.toString(), encodedPassword);
}
```

So I tried this piece of code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String salt = BCrypt.gensalt(12);
    String clearText="test";
    String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw(clearText, salt);
    String reHashed = BCrypt.hashpw(clearText, hashed);

    System.out.println("salt : " + salt);
    System.out.println(hashed);
    System.out.println(reHashed);
}
```

**output** :

```
salt : $2a$12$gzUymsNBoW.f1OfkLpb2se
$2a$12$gzUymsNBoW.f1OfkLpb2seFZrniorawujSOp6Qe.PWDIHJvmYSP6y
$2a$12$gzUymsNBoW.f1OfkLpb2seFZrniorawujSOp6Qe.PWDIHJvmYSP6y
```

This seems to confirm that :

```
good password => hashed = hash(clearPassword, hashed)
```

Am I understanding it wrong? Does it mean that the salt is useless for password checking? Hence, does it mean that I do not need to store the salt in database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BCrypt stores the salt as part of the "hash" string that it returns.
This is handled by the `Bcrypt.*` functions, so you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is the equality between `hashed` and `reHashed` specific to BCrypt implementation?